# Node.js Threads Shared Memory Access

Tags: node.js, caching

Is there anything that is similar to PHP's APC (Alternative PHP Cache) for Node.js?

So every Node.js thread running on a server can access the cache. I know the architecture of Node.js may not easily or at all allow for an APC like cache.

I know we can of course run memcache on each server as well to create a server level cache but was curious of there was any alternative.

thanks

Comment: What kind of threading are you using?

Comment: using cluster to run 1 thread per core

Comment: [vert.x](http://vertx.io) apparently has [intraprocess communication](http://vertxproject.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/where-vert-x-delivers-over-node/). Yeah its not node but it's very similiar

Answer (score 1):

Node is trying to keep only the basic stuff in its API, so you won't find such a thing "baked in" (for example WebSockets isn't included in Node core, but in external modules).

You would need to create such a cache layer using something like Redis or Memcached.

P.S. You should better refer to Node processes instead of threads, since you don't have to handle threading stuff with Node.

Comment: appreciate it. yeah we already have memcache but was hoping for something just a touch faster and something we don't have to monitor like APC. guess we'll just have to stick with memcache on each server for now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this module helps at all.
I can't guarantee its' reliability and I never kept my promise to do a Windows API as I'm a bit of a linux snob (as in nothing Microsoft comes near my PC)

https://github.com/dazhazit/node-ipcbuffer

It implements a simple byte buffer between processes. You could probably build any mechanism you like on top of it.